# A mapping $T:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^m}$ is one-to-one if each vector in $\mathbb{R^n}$ maps onto a unique vector in $\mathbb{R^m}$.

Tags: linear-transformations

I'm reading **Linear Algebra and Its Applications** by David C. Lay, Steven R. Lay and Judi J. McDonald.

In section 1.9 exercise 24 there's a following statement

> d) A mapping $T:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^m}$ is one-to-one if each vector in $\mathbb{R^n}$ maps onto a unique vector in $\mathbb{R^m}$.

According to Solutions Manual for the book this statement is **false** and I struggle to see why this is the case.

Comment: do you understand why there are functions that aren't injective?

Comment: That’s a pretty complicated bit of MathJax to get an ugly version of `\mathbb R` ($\mathbb R$.)

Comment: The issue is that the word "unique" here is used in a manner that is easily misunderstood. It's awkward wording to a faulty degree. When it says "a vector is mapped to a unique vector", it simply means that if $x$ is in the domain, there is one and only one $b$ in the codomain such that $T(x)=b$. Note that the $x$ in this statement is fixed beforehand, it does not say anything about how the values $T(x)$ for different $x$ relate.

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes a lot of sense @Thorgott.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews noted. I'm not particularly good at \LaTeX, had to google as I went.

Comment: But yes, the question is terribly worded. Practically designed to be misinterpreted. Pedagogically useless.

Comment: @Thorgott thank you for clearing it up for me. I'll answer and rewrite my question a bit to make sure that if someone will google it they will find an answer.

Comment: @schuk Where does it give the answer to exercise 24 section 1.9 in Lay?

Comment: @Coriolanus good point. It is in a Solutions Manual actually, the book gives answers only to odd numbered exercises.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is misleadingly phrased. What truly meant is

> A mapping $T:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^m}$ is one-to-one if every vector $\mathbf{x}\in$ $\mathbb{R^n}$ maps onto some vector $\mathbf{b}\in$ $\mathbb{R^m}$.

, or in other words,

> Is it true that if transformation $T:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^m}$ is consistent for every vector $\mathbf{x}\in$ $\mathbb{R^n}$ it is also a **one-to-one** mapping from $\mathbb{R^n}$ to $\mathbb{R^m}$?